# Add a subview to a UITableView cell's view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm attempting to add a subview (which contains a UIDatePicker) to the view of a UITableView cell when that cell is selected. However, when I select that cell, the content of the subview is not being displayed.

Below is where I check to see if the user selects the cell that I want to add the subview to:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == SectionOne && indexPath.row == RowOne && self.datePickerIsShowing == NO){

        [self.RowOne addSubview:_datePicker];
        [self showDatePickerCell];
    } else{
        [self hideDatePickerCell];
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Additionally, below is how I create the date picker and show it:

```
- (void)createDatePicker{
    _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
    _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    _datePicker.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];
}


- (void)showDatePickerCell {
    self.datePickerIsShowing = YES;
    self.datePicker.hidden = NO;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Show date picker");
}
```

And below is how I set the selected row to be the required height to show the date picker:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
        if (indexPath.section == SectionOne && indexPath.row == RowOne && self.datePickerIsShowing == YES){
                rowHeight = kDatePickerCellHeight;
    }
    else{
        rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
    }
    return rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: check _datePickermight be nil. may be not initialized

Comment: I know that it's not nil, as earlier I accidentally added it to the TableView's view and the picker showed up, before I realized that I actually need to add it to a cell view.

Comment: check whether you have set frame or not. I have posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are missing the frame for UIDatePicker. You need to initialize with frame.Or Have you set the frame other place in your code.

```
    - (void)createDatePicker{
        _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRect(0,0,100,20)];
        _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
        _datePicker.clipsToBounds = YES;
        _datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell =[UITableViewCell cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == SectionOne && indexPath.row == RowOne && self.datePickerIsShowing == NO){

        [cell addSubview:_datePicker];
        [self showDatePickerCell];
    } else{
        [self hideDatePickerCell];
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Your answer helped solve part of my problem. I added initWithFrame as you suggested (I hadn't set the frame anywhere else yet), but the date-picker still isn't appearing as a subview of my table-view cell.

Comment: Yea It was added but without frame size. So its width and heigh was 0.

Comment: Thank you, I should have caught that. 
However, I changed the height/width values, but still no success :/

Comment: now is it working fine? are you still getting issue.

Comment: No, it's still not displaying the date picker :/

Comment: Problem here i see that didSelectRowAtIndexPath you are adding to self.RowOne I am not sure this is right object fro tableCellView Try this way    UITableViewCell *cell =[UITableViewCell cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; [cell add subView _datePicker];

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I needed, thank you! If you put it in an answer format, then I'll accept it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding views to a UITableViewCell won't work. Add them to the UITableViewCell's contentView instead.

That said, adding views in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not really a good thing to do. What happens if I select the row twice? What happens if I scroll so that row is no longer visible (the cell will be reused, still with datepicker attached. You'll need to handle prepareForReuse properly at a minimum.